# Show That One Can Find a Subgroup $H \lt G$ Such That $H/Z(G) = Z(G/Z(G))$

Tags: group-theory

Show that one can find a subgroup $H \lt G$ such that $H/Z(G) = Z(G/Z(G))$ and that this subgroup can be defined as follows: $a \in H \iff \forall b \in G, [a,b] \in Z(G) $.

My *failed* attempt:

In other words: $H=\{a, \forall b \in G, [a,b] \in Z(G)\} = \{a, \forall b \in G, a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \in Z(G)\} =  \{a, \forall b \in G, a^{-1}b^{-1}ab = bab^{-1}a^{-1}\}$

Now let us see what $H/Z(G)$ and $Z(G/Z(G)) represent:

- $H/Z(G) = \{hZ(G) , h\in H\} =  \{hZ(G) s.t \forall b \in G, h^{-1}b^{-1}hb=bhb^{-1}h^{-1}\}$ That's as far as I can get.
- $Z(G/Z(G)) = \{g\in G/Z(G) s.t. gh=hg \forall h \in G/Z(G)\}$

Now I really don't know where I am going, some indications would be welcomed.

Comment: One can note that $G=G$ is an example for an abelian group $G$. For any group with trivial center, one can take $H=\{e\}$, I'm sure there are less trivial examples.

Comment: I believe I am to show that the H defined respects the equality for any group G.

Comment: So you mean, that for any group, you can find such a subgroup?

Comment: I believe so yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows at once from the [Correspondence Theorem](http://www.thomasbeatty.com/MATH%20PAGES/ARCHIVES%20-%20NOTES/Algebra/Correspondence%20Theorem.pdf) : $\;G/Z(G)\;$ is a well defined group, and thus its center, $\;Z(G/Z(G))\;$ is a subgroup which, by the above mentioned theorem, corrresponds to some $\;H\le G\;$ , with $\;Z(G)\le H\;$ , s.t. $\;H/Z(G)=Z(G/Z(G))\;$

The characterization of $\;H\;$ follows from the definition of "center of group":

$$xZ(G)\in H/Z(G)=Z(G/Z(G))\iff \forall\,g\in G\;,\;\;xZ(G)gZ(G)=gZ(G)xZ(G)\iff$$

$$xgZ(G)=gxZ(G)\iff (xg)^{-1}gxZ(G)\in Z(G)\iff$$

$$(xg)^{-1}gx=g^{-1}x^{-1}gx=[g,x]\in Z(G)\le H $$

Answer (score 0):

Denote the projection $G\to G/Z(G)$ by $p$. This exists since the center is normal.

Note that $[b, a]\in Z(G)$ for all $b$ if and only if $[p(a), p(b)]=p([a, b])=e$ for all $b$, which is true if and only if $p(a)\in Z(G/Z(G))$. Thus if we let $H=\{a|\forall b, [a,b]\in Z(G)\}$, then $H/Z(G)=p(H)=Z(G/Z(G))$.

Comment: Why does the normality of $Z(G)$ imply the existence of the projection p?

Comment: Also, by "0" do you mean the identity element of $G$?

Comment: @Pax What does "...if $\;H\;$ is defined as given..." mean? Given...by whom, where, how?

Comment: @DonAntonio H is defined as:  $a \in H \iff \forall b \in G, [a,b] \in Z(G) $. Given by me, here on mathstackexchange and through the letters on my keyboard (^^)

Comment: @SylvesterStallone Normality of a subgroup is equivalent to there existing a group structure on $G/Z(G)$ and a map $G\to G/Z(G)$ given by projection. This should be in the first chapter of any book on group theory.

Comment: @SylvesterStallone That is *the second part* of the claim to be proved, imo. But I guess one can as well prove that characterization defines a subgroup  $\;H\;$ and *then* prove it fulfills what it is asked. Ok.